# How to insert objects through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs

I have stored group of objects into one array called 'resData' and i'm having one more array of data called 'approvedIds', there have included all approved id's. Here i want to match these two arrays and add one new key into 'resData' array like 'approveStatus:"approve"'. How to do this one in javascript?

All data's,

```
var resData = [
    {
        firstName:"Jhon",
        lastName:"adam",
        emailId:"jhn12@gmail.com",
        id:"01"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Kyle",
        lastName:"Miller",
        emailId:"kl12@gmail.com",
        id:"02"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Jhonathan",
        lastName:"adam",
        emailId:"jadm12@gmail.com",
        id:"03"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Lewis",
        lastName:"harber",
        emailId:"lewh12@gmail.com",
        id:"04"
    }
];
```

Approved id's array,

```
var approvedIds = ['01', '03'];
```

My output will be like this,

```
var resData = [
        {
            firstName:"Jhon",
            lastName:"adam",
            emailId:"jhn12@gmail.com",
            id:"01",
            approveStatus:'approved'
        },
        {
            firstName:"Kyle",
            lastName:"Miller",
            emailId:"kl12@gmail.com",
            id:"02"
        },
        {
            firstName:"Jhonathan",
            lastName:"adam",
            emailId:"jadm12@gmail.com",
            id:"03",
            approveStatus:'approved'
        },
        {
            firstName:"Lewis",
            lastName:"harber",
            emailId:"lewh12@gmail.com",
            id:"04"
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this. Use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [**indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) functions

```js
var resData = [
    {
        firstName:"Jhon",
        lastName:"adam",
        emailId:"jhn12@gmail.com",
        id:"01"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Kyle",
        lastName:"Miller",
        emailId:"kl12@gmail.com",
        id:"02"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Jhonathan",
        lastName:"adam",
        emailId:"jadm12@gmail.com",
        id:"03"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Lewis",
        lastName:"harber",
        emailId:"lewh12@gmail.com",
        id:"04"
    }
];


var approvedIds = ['01', '03'];

resData.forEach(item => {
  if(approvedIds.indexOf(item.id) !== -1){
       item.approvedStatus = 'approved';
    }
} );

console.log(resData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6 array functions, which is more functional and doesn't alter the original objects:

```js
var resData = [
    {
        firstName:"Jhon",
        lastName:"adam",
        emailId:"jhn12@gmail.com",
        id:"01"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Kyle",
        lastName:"Miller",
        emailId:"kl12@gmail.com",
        id:"02"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Jhonathan",
        lastName:"adam",
        emailId:"jadm12@gmail.com",
        id:"03"
    },
    {
        firstName:"Lewis",
        lastName:"harber",
        emailId:"lewh12@gmail.com",
        id:"04"
    }
];

var approvedIds = ['01', '03'];

//Solution:
var newData = resData
                 .filter(rd => approvedIds.indexOf(rd.id) >= 0)
                 .map(rd => Object.assign({}, rd, {approvedStatus: "approved"}));

console.log(newData, resData);
```